# Screwturn scripting not working?

Tags: iis, windows-server-2008, screwturn

I had previously installed screwturn on windows 7 iis and the site was functioning 100%

I have recently installed it on Win Server2008 and it would appear that the scripts are not working.

The website works tabs and logins ok. The problem is in the providers tab, if I click on any displays or on the 'select' label nothing happens. When I had installed this on the windows 7 iis these were clearly working.

All roles should be in place, ISS server, application server.
Do I need to enable anything specific on the server or am I missing a configuration?

Comment: I would surgest using fiddler to monitor the request from the client to ensure everything is been downloaded.

Answer (score 1):

SOLVED THE ISSUE"!!!!!#
just downgraded the framework from 4.0 to 2.0 and worked perfectly

Comment: I'm using the 2.0 framework for the ApplicationPool, as well. I have some notes @ http://www.xradiograph.com/Programming/ScrewTurnWiki#installation

Comment: The project originators have closed-down, but some people are trying to keep the project going @ https://stw.codeplex.com (NB: I am one of those people) You're welcome to join!

Answer (score 0):

I vaguely remember similar issues when running under .NET 4.0 (are you?) - do you have these fixes in your Web.config?

```
<pages validateRequest="false">
<httpRuntime requestValidationMode="2.0"/>
```

Comment: yes it is all under 4.0. just added them. still same issue :(